# Hiding of row count in ag grid aggregation / row grouping

Tags: ag-grid

Is there a way to hide the row count in the aggregated rows in ag-grid? 
I couldn't find any specific configuration to hide the row count appearning beside the aggregated cell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`suppressCount`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/#grid-renderer-aggroupcellrenderer) within `cellRendererParams`

```
cellRendererParams: {
    suppressCount: true, // turn off the row count
}
```

Comment: You can also use this within autoGroupColumnDef

Answer (score 9):

The last two answers do not seem to work in v25 of the ag-Grid.

See this page: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/grouping/

The solution for me is to use the `autoGroupColumnDef` like the following:

```
autoGroupColumnDef: {
    cellRendererParams: {
        suppressCount: true
    }
}
```

Comment: works on v24.1 too

Answer (score 5):

When using `gridOptions.groupUseEntireRow = true` you can set it with

```
gridOptions.groupRowRendererParams = {
  suppressCount: true
};
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed even with the newer version of Ag-Grid